# $f$ is a meromorphic function, Suprimum of the number of solutions to $f(z)=w$ is finite. Then $f$ is rational.

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is a meromorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$. For each $w \in \mathbb{C}$ we denote by 
$N_{f}(w)$ the number of solutions to the equation $f(z)=w$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Prove that if $\sup_{w\in \mathbb{C}}\ N_{f}(w)<\infty$ then $f$ is a rational function.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*HINT:* In the light of the Picard theorem, can $f$ have an essential singularity in $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$? After that: How many poles can $f$ have? What do we know about $1/f$?